# Subscriptions with Paypal (Netflix Style)

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, paypal, uwp, paypal-subscriptions

Hey any of you know what I need to do to get PayPal to have recurring payments, but just like Netflix, where the user authorizes Netflix to get X amount of money?

I looked all over and I can't seem to find how is that called or how to implement.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't use any Netflix before, but how it charged you via subscriptions?

Comment: It is called subscription or recurring payment https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring. You can even do it with a button https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/get-started/recurring-payment-processing

Answer (score 0):

There are two concepts/products in PayPal that handle subscription - one is [Recurring Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/) which automatically bill the buyer a **fixed** amount on a **fixed** schedule,  and the other is [Reference Transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/), which handles subscription of **varying** amounts on a **varying** schedule.

I don't know how Netflix charges user, but it sounds more like Reference Transactions. The bad news is that Reference Transactions is mainly for PayPal partners or large merchants, and it's not easy to apply for it. You may want to contact PayPal customer service for more details.